# Redirect Subdirectory to root domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

I want to redirect an entire subdirectory on my site i.e. http://www.mydomain.com/subdirectory to the root domain of my site http://www.mydomain.com can someone please tell my how to do so via .htaccess?

I had tried with Cpanel and enabled wildcard redirect but, sadly it's not working!

The subdirectory is actually a separate WordPress installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look into this: [301 redirection](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/web-redirection.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

Put the following .htaccess file into the root directory:

```
Redirect /subdirectory http://www.example.com
```

(requires `mod_alias` to be loaded) or use `mod_redirect` and put the .htaccess file into the subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1
```

See: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ for mod_rewrite documentation.